# Managing Configuration Changes in WCF

Tags: wcf, configurationmanager

What is the preferable way to manage configuration file changes in WCF *webservices*? I know usually in desktop applications people use a `FileSystemWatcher` to watch for changes in `App.config`, but how exactly does one go about configuring one in WCF? I tried using something like the following code:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    private static readonly FileSystemWatcher ConfigurationWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(PathToRootDirectory);

    private void ReloadConfiguration(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
    }

    // IService implementation goes here.

    static Service()
    {
        ConfigurationWatcher.Filter = "web.config";
        ConfigurationWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilter.LastWrite;
        ConfigurationWatcher.Change += ReloadConfiguration;
    }
}
```

However, that didn't seem to work since `ConfigurationWatcher` seemed to being initialized upon every call to the service... How does one go about accomplishing this?

Comment: This works automatically for an IIS-hosted service. How are you hosting your service?

Comment: It it IIS-hosted indeed! Thank you so much, then!

Answer (score 1):

This happens automatically for a service hosted in IIS.

Any change to the web.config or any assembly in the bin folder will cause the current AppDomain to shut down and a new AppDomain to be started for subsequent requests - just like with ASP.NET.